# Are there anyway to retrieve signalized junctions from yandex?

Tags: traffic, yandex

I need to detect the signalized junctions. Yandex maps have traffic lights icon if any traffic lights exist. Are there any way to get these traffic lights icons location from Yandex map?

[image: Traffic lights on a junction in Yandex map]

Comment: Can you give an example, location screenshot?

Comment: @Mapperz Added sir